# Microsoft.Web.Services2 replacement in .Net framework 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services

I have .net application in framework 1.1 in which `Microsoft.Web.Services2` is used. Now, this is being migrated from 1.1 to 4.5 framework. Could you please let me know the replacement of `Microsoft.Web.Services2` in framework 4.5?

Please note that I can't use WCF for replacing `Microsoft.Web.Services2` component. I need to use `Microsoft.Web.Services` or `Service.Model` class.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use WCF?

Comment: OK If I decide to convert WSE2.0 to WCF then what is the easiest way to do it?